# Using R to search SharePoint directories for specific files

Tags: r, sharepoint

Using R, I'm trying to search a SharePoint directory for file names that contain the text "Admin". I'm working on a Linux environment, so I assume I have to authenticate.

The code below works on my Windows laptop, where top_folder is a SharePoint site:

```
    top_folder <- "//folder1/folder2"  
    file_details <- file.info(list.files(path = top_folder, pattern = 
    "Admin", full.names=TRUE, recursive=TRUE))  
    print(file_details)
```

I can't get this same code to work on a Linux environment. Below is what I tried on Linux. The code seems to authenticate, but not sure how to search for files from here. I appreciate any guidance!

```
    require(httr)  
    set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))  
    url <- "https://folder1/folder1"  
    r = GET(url, authenticate("userID","password",type="basic"))
```